# is it possible to submit a form with already existing entities in Spring? If yes, how?

Tags: java, spring, form-submit

here is the jsp:

```xml
<c:if test="${!empty USERS}">
    <form:form method="post" action="requestForFriends.html" commandName="user">
        <form:select path="userName">
            <c:forEach items="${USERS}" var="user">
                <form:option value="${user.userName}"></form:option>
            </c:forEach>
        </form:select>

        <input type="submit" value="Send freindship request" />
    </form:form>
</c:if>
```

here is the controller's relevant part:

```java
@RequestMapping("/toAddFriend")
public ModelAndView toAddNewFriend() {
    Map<String, Object> model = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    model.put("USERS", userService.getUsers());
    ModelAndView ret=new ModelAndView("addFriend", model);
    ret.addObject("user", new User());

    return ret;
}
```

if I do the code above then a brand new User object will be created when I submit the form. But when I click "submit" **I would like to get one of the ALREADY EXISTING User instance**, which are clearly present in here:

```xml
<c:forEach items="${USERS}" var="user">
    <form:option value="${user.userName}"></form:option>
```

How can I modify my code to get the existing object?
Actually I know an ugly way to get the existing instance. By submitting the form I can create a new User instance with the same username as the one has that I am looking for. Then in the DaoImpl class I can query for the "old" User which shares the userName with the newly created one. But I guess it is quite wasteful and ugly so I can't believe that there is no better way.

**UPDATE**

```
   <!-- language: lang-java -->

 @RequestMapping(value = "/requestForFriends", method = RequestMethod.POST)
        public ModelAndView requestNewFriend(@ModelAttribute("user") User user, BindingResult result) {
            System.out.println(user.getUserName());
                System.out.println(user.getEmail());
                Map<String, Object> model = new HashMap<String, Object>();
                model.put("USERS", userService.getUsers());
                ModelAndView ret=new ModelAndView("addFriend", model);
                ret.addObject("user", new User());

                return ret;

            }
```

Comment: Can you add Controller mapped to requestForFriends.html code? What **exactly** doesn't work now in your current code?

Comment: @ Xaerxess: I get new instances with null values instead of getting existing instances with existing values. As for the first part of your comment I don't know how to do it, since I am quite a beginner...

Comment: I meant the (Java?) code responsible for `action="requestForFriends.html"` handling. If you use command, as in your example, it's probably [`@ModelAttribute`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-modelattrib-method-args) annotated parameter that represents your form, with all selected options populated.

Comment: It seems like if you want to get an existing user, you would need to pass in some sort of ID then do a lookup.  I am looking at your code, and it appears you are creating a new one each time.  Maybe I am missing something?  Can you clarify a bit?

Comment: @ Xaerxess please find the java code responsible for action="requestForFriends.html" 
Sadly the user I get there is a brand new user that happened to have the same name as the "old" one but it's email is empty. I do not need the NEW user, I want the EXISTING (old) user but I do not know how to send it.

Comment: &CodeChimp _I am looking at your code, and it appears you are creating a new one each time_ Yes, it is true, and it is my problem. I am creating a new one because I do not know how to pass the old one. Let me summarize what I want: On the jsp page there is ${USERS} that contains many User entities. Since they are in a <form:select I want to pass the selected entity to the Java code responsible for action="requestForFriends.html". I dont want to create a NEW user. I do it **ONLY** because I do not know how to pass the existing one. Feel free to delete or add anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  @ModelAttribute
    public void fillUsers(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("USERS", userService.getUsers());
    }

    @ModelAttribute
    public void getUser(@RequestParam(required = false) String userName, Model model) {
        User user = null;
        if (userName != null) {
            user = userService.getUserByName(userName);
        }
        if (user == null) {
            user = new User();
        }
        model.addAttribute("user", user);
    }

    @RequestMapping("/toAddFriend")
    public String toAddNewFriend() {
        return "addFriend";

    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/requestForFriends", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String requestNewFriend(@ModelAttribute("user") User user) {
        System.out.println(user.getUserName());
        System.out.println(user.getEmail());
        return "addFriend";

    }
```